# Can I use OpenType stylistic sets in Blender?

Tags: font

I have purchased the [Sagittarius font](https://www.typography.com/fonts/sagittarius/how-to-use) from Hoefler&Co which contains a bunch of very cool OpenType "stylistic sets", such as for example the image below, "MICR Delimeters",  but there are a lot more (see the link above).

Can these be activated in Blender without exporting SVGs from another application?

[image]